# How can I display the values from my DB (phpmyadmin) into a drop-down-box in unity?

Tags: c#, database, unity-game-engine, drop-down-menu

I am new in codding and I couldn't find any solution to solve my issue.
I just need to see the data from the database in my drop-down-box in Unity.

Please give me advices step by step.

Answer (score 0):

I managed for now to connect to the DB.

```
    <?php

    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $dbname = "database";

    // create conntection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

    // check connection
     if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
     }
     $sql = "SELECT item_name FROM items";
     $result = $conn->query($sql);
     if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
         // output data of each row
             while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
             echo "-".$row["item_name"]. "<br>";
         }
     }
    $conn->close();
?>
```